# What does the @ in this code sample mean?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, keyword, variable-names

`Html.TextBox("ParentPassword", "", new { @class = "required" })`

what the gosh darned heck is the @ for the @class.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`class` is a reserved keyword, so you can't use this as a variable name.

The @ operator allows you to get around this rule.  The reason why its being done here is that the anonymous object is used to populate attributes on a HTML element.  A valid attribute name is "class", which lets you set the CSS class on the element.

Answer (score 8):

`class` is a keyword. To use `class` as the name of a variable/property, in C#, you can prepend `@` to it, as `@class`. In the IL, for all .net is concerned, the name of the variable/property is still `class` - `@` is the way you have to do it in C#.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add my two cents to all the right answers here:

If you are new to C# but familiar to VB.NET, you probably know that there is a correspondent to @ in VB. The square brackets [ ] are used in VB.NET to surround a variable name that is named after a reserved word (or keyword). For example:

```
Dim [String] As String
```